# Python string to list (based on tags)

Tags: python, list

I do not want to use an XML Parser (i dont see the point for the small amount of work i am doing).

I have an XML File stored as a String and want to create list or split it based on a tag:

```
<xmlval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
</xmlval>
<xmlval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
</xmlval>
<xmlval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
</xmlval>
<xmlval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
</xmlval>
<xmlval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
  <anotherval></anotherval>
</xmlval>
```

I want to split it into a list based on `<xmlval>`

Comment: everyone is going to tell you to use one...

Comment: `I want to split it into a list based on` what?

Comment: Please provide an example with some values and the actual output you would expect. Oh, and use an XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Really, an XML parser is *the* way to go for such a small task. Use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(inputfile)

somelist = []

for elem in tree.findall('xmlval'):
    text = ' '.join(elem.findall('./anotherval/text()'))
    somelist.append(text)
```

There, that wasn't so bad, was it?

Comment: As long as you don't scare OP off by showing the one-line list comprehension: `somelist = [' '.join(elem.findall('./anotherval/text()')) for elem in tree.findall('xmlval')]`

Comment: @hughdbrown: Exactly. I wanted to keep it simple and easily comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

```
b=[]
for i in string.split('<xmlval>'):
    for j in i.split('</xmlval>'):
        b.append(j)
```

Will have the string that is split by tags `<xmlval>` and `</xmlval>` tags